# ITextsharp get "at least one signature requires validating" after add annotation

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to add a annotation free text into signed PDF using ITextsharp. After add the annotation to the PDF and open in adobe reader, it will show the message "**At least one signature requires validating...**" on the op. If I add annotation into signed PDF using adobe reader, it won't show the message.

Here is my C# code and using the itextsharp 5.5.8

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms, '\0', true);

            Rectangle annotRect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 150, 150);

            PdfContentByte canvas = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte(stamper.Writer);

            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\mingliu.ttc,0", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            canvas.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
            canvas.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.RED);

            PdfAnnotation annotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateFreeText(stamper.Writer, annotRect, "test", canvas);

            annotation.Flags = PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_READONLY | PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_LOCKED | PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT;


            PdfDate pdfdate = new PdfDate();
            annotation.Title = "test";
            annotation.Put(PdfName.CREATIONDATE, pdfdate);
            annotation.Put(PdfName.M, pdfdate);
            stamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, 1);

            stamper.Close();
            reader.Close();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Depending on the kind of signature, adding annotations may be forbidden. Thus, please share a sample signed PDF with which the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks Mkl, the file in <a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5tk7KqtLjSzbTU0cGZ2bkZXTlk/view?usp=sharing">here</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is *not*, as I first assumed, that the signature existing in the document to stamp forbids adding annotations.

Instead the problem here is that Adobe Reader (I tested with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC version 2015.009.20079) only recognizes annotations (and then accepts them as allowed changes after signing) if they fulfill some extra criteria.

By trial and error I found out that I can make the Reader recognize your free text annotation if I provide the optional **RC** annotation dictionary entry. According to the spec:

> **RC** text string
>   or text
>   stream
>   *(Optional; PDF 1.5)* A rich text string (see 12.7.3.4, “Rich Text Strings”)
>   that shall be used to generate the appearance of the annotation.
>
> *(Table 174 – Additional entries specific to a free text annotation - in [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

I added it like this (borrowing from a text annotation I created using Acrobat):

```
annotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateFreeText(stamper.Writer, annotRect, "test", canvas);

annotation.Put(PdfName.RC, new PdfString("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><body xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:xfa=\"http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/\" xfa:APIVersion=\"Acrobat:9.5.5\" xfa:spec=\"2.0.2\"  style=\"font-size:12.0pt;text-align:left;color:#FF0000;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;font-stretch:normal\"><p dir=\"ltr\"><span style=\"font-family:Helvetica\">test</span></p></body>"));
```

Without that the Reader displays the PDF like this:

[image: annotated sample PDF, original code]

... and with it like this:

[image: annotated sample PDF, enhanced code]

As you see the Reader shows the annotation on the signature panel only after adding the **RC** value.

Comment: Thanks mkl, it is working for me and thanks for your the specification document. the document is very helpful for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have another question regarding to Chinese content. If i input Chinese content(測試) for the annotation, it cannot display the content even i set the font family to MingLiU or AdobeMingStd-Light

Comment: As that is a different question (instead of *how to annotate without breaking signatures* now *how to annotate with Chinese content*), please make it a stackoverflow question in its own right. Furthermore, please supply in that question the source code and data necessary to reproduce this new issue.