# Annotation content not appearing with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

Update: This is working in adobe reader, but not in the osx default pdf reader. Many of our users use the default osx reader so ideally I could get it working there, I know it supports annotations)

I am using Apache PDFBox 2.0.22 to try and add annotations to a pdf programmatically. The code I have runs, and produces a pdf with an annotation, but the content's text of the annotation is empty (See screenshot). What am I doing wrong?

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColor;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotation;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationTextMarkup;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class Sample{



  public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("test.pdf"));

    try {
      //insert new page
      PDPage page = (PDPage) doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);

      List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();

      //generate instanse for annotation
      PDAnnotationTextMarkup txtMark = new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_HIGHLIGHT);

      //set the rectangle
      PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
      position.setLowerLeftX(170);
      position.setLowerLeftY(125);
      position.setUpperRightX(195);
      position.setUpperRightY(140);
      txtMark.setRectangle(position);

      //set the quadpoint
      float[] quads = new float[8];
      //x1,y1
      quads[0] = position.getLowerLeftX();
      quads[1] = position.getUpperRightY() - 2;
      //x2,y2
      quads[2] = position.getUpperRightX();
      quads[3] = quads[1];
      //x3,y3
      quads[4] = quads[0];
      quads[5] = position.getLowerLeftY() - 2;
      //x4,y4
      quads[6] = quads[2];
      quads[7] = quads[5];
      txtMark.setQuadPoints(quads);
      txtMark.setAnnotationName("My annotation");
      txtMark.setTitlePopup("title popup");
      txtMark.setContents("Highlighted since it's important");
      txtMark.setRichContents("Here is some rich content");
      PDColor blue = new PDColor(new float[] { 0, 0, 1 }, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
      txtMark.setColor(blue);


      annotations.add(txtMark);

      page.setAnnotations(annotations);

      doc.save("test-out.pdf");

    }finally
    {
      doc.close();
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please try calling `txtMark.constructAppearances()` and tell whether that works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that does not seem to change anything. Any other ideas?

Comment: update! It's working in adobe reader but not in the default osx pdf reader. Id love to have this work in both but I guess this is a start

Comment: If you open the file with Adobe Reader make a minor change in the annotation and save it, does it display in OSX?

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Then it means there's a bug in OSX. Because Adobe usually "repairs" documents when saving, i.e. any (assumed) PDFBox shortcomings should be gone.

Comment: You might compare internals of a document with text displayed to one with text not displayed. Or you might share such examples to help you compare.

Comment: Ok thanks @TilmanHausherr. Btw, is there a place I can go to ask about sponsorship of pdfbox features? My company would like to sponsor some work.

Comment: You could ask on the users mailing list. But don't expect anything, the "core" people all have their day jobs.

Answer (score 0):

just adding this as an answer to have a better formatting.

PDFBOX is constantly changing, and maybe .constructAppearances() works better at some point - but meanwhile, ... I myself followed the advice to create my own appearance stream for the annotation. But it still did not appear to work. I had tried everything, it seemed - and in every case sometimes the annotations would appear in Acrobat Reader DC, but they would not show in Chrome or Firefox default PDF viewer.

First of all - if you setContent() on the annotation object itself, AND if you don't supply your own appearance stream - the viewers like Acrobat Reader DC will sometimes try to construct their own version of appearance - which varies across viewers - now if you supply your own, .. some viewers will still construct their own.. e.g. interactive elements like a small yellow icon that indicates that we have an annotation here and which shows the contents if you hover the mouse cursor over it - that's why, I guess, some of the programmers will try to not call setContent() (?)

Moreover, if you, like me, choose to use PDAnnotationTextMarkup with the SUB_TYPE_FREETEXT subtype - to just write something over the existing PDF, Acrobat Reader DC specifically will attempt to create its own visual something - it seems that it tries to modify (to correct?) the contents of the document, producing and showing a slightly changed version, which will result in existing digital signatures changing state - we can overcome this problem according to this [SO q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218823/itextsharp-get-at-least-one-signature-requires-validating-after-add-annotation).

But it seems that there is a better way to write a static text over the PDF which Acrobat Reader DC will not try to modify, and it's the Rubber Stamp annotation. You can plainly substitute PDAnnotationTextMarkup (and PDFBOX 3.0.0 has another name for that..) with PDAnnotationRubberStamp. Everything else stays the same.

So what I was doing wrong in all my annotations code was to misplace the bounding box for the annotation's appearance. setBBox function takes as a parameter a PDRectangle, and PDAnnotation.getRectangle() returns a PDRectangle - but the first cannot use the second as is! Because the second PDRectangle coordinates are in relation to the page's lower left corner, while we need a rectangle that has 0, 0 as X, Y.

So the code that I came up with is as follows (and I haven't yet starting with _font and the font embedding in general which seems like a huge topic..):

```
private void addAnnotation(String name, PDDocument doc, PDPage page, float x, float y, String text) throws IOException {
  
  List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
  PDAnnotationRubberStamp t = new PDAnnotationRubberStamp();

  t.setAnnotationName(name); // might play important role
  t.setPrinted(true); // always visible
  t.setReadOnly(true); // does not interact with user
  t.setContents(text); 
    
  // calculate realWidth, realHeight according to font size (e.g. using _font.getStringWidth(text))         
  float realWidth = 100, realHeight = 100;  
  PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(x, y, realWidth, realHeight);
  t.setRectangle(rect);

  PDAppearanceDictionary ap = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
  ap.setNormalAppearance(createAppearanceStream(doc, t));
  t.setAppearance(ap);
  
  annotations.add(t);
  page.setAnnotations(annotations);

  // these must be set for incremental save to work properly (PDFBOX < 3.0.0 at least?)  
  ap.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
  t.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
  page.getResources().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
  page.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
  doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
  doc.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);      
}

private void modifyAppearanceStream(PDAppearanceStream aps, PDAnnotation ann) throws IOException {
  PDAppearanceContentStream apsContent = null;
  
  try {
     PDRectangle rect = ann.getRectangle();
     rect = new PDRectangle(0, 0, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight()); // need to be relative - this is mega important because otherwise it appears as if nothing is printed
     aps.setBBox(rect); // set bounding box to the dimensions of the annotation itself
     
     // embed our unicode font (NB: yes, this needs to be done otherwise aps.getResources() == null which will cause NPE later during setFont)
     PDResources res = new PDResources();
     _fontName = res.add(_font).getName(); // okay I create _font elsewhere
     aps.setResources(res);
     
     // draw directly on the XObject's content stream
     apsContent = new PDAppearanceContentStream(aps);

     apsContent.beginText();
     apsContent.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, _fontSize); // _font
     apsContent.setTextMatrix(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(0, 1));
     apsContent.showText(ann.getContents());
     apsContent.endText();
  }
  finally {
     if (apsContent != null) {
        try { apsContent.close(); } catch (Exception ex) { log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex); }
     }
  }      

  aps.getResources().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
  aps.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
}

private  PDAppearanceStream createAppearanceStream(final PDDocument document, PDAnnotation ann) throws IOException
{
  PDAppearanceStream aps = new PDAppearanceStream(document);
  modifyAppearanceStream(aps, ann);
  return aps;
}
```

Comment: note - I've worked with above code on PDFBOX v2.0.21