# "At least one signature is invalid" After adding stamp in Signed PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to add stamp or image annotation in a signed PDF but it gives me an "invalid signature" error and, after moving this annotation, it gives me an "at least one signature required validating" error. How can I solve this?

I also found a solution but for text annotation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218823/itextsharp-get-at-least-one-signature-requires-validating-after-add-annotation).
It worked fine with text annotation but I cannot do the same for the stamp.

```
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(@"D:\\11.jpg");
float w = 100;
float h = 100;
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle location = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(36, 770 - h, 36 + w, 770);

PdfAnnotation stamp = PdfAnnotation.CreateStamp(stamper.Writer, location, null, "ITEXT");
img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
PdfAppearance app = cb.CreateAppearance(100, 100);
app.AddImage(img);
stamp.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, app);
stamper.AddAnnotation(stamp, 1);
```

Comment: *"It worked fine with text annotation but I cannot do the same for the stamp"* - Why not? What happens when you try?

Comment: It gives me corrupt signature invalid and when I move the ann. it converted to at least one signature needed to validate
This is the same as text ann but i added image instead
I added this line after setting SetAppearance
 stamp.Put(PdfName.RC, new PdfString("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><body xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:xfa=\"http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/\" xfa:APIVersion=\"Acrobat:9.5.5\" xfa:spec=\"2.0.2\"  ><img src=\"D:\\11.jpg\" alt=\"img\" width=\"500\" height=\"600\"></body>"));

Comment: When I open file i get this message
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IpSkC1Mw3DnsOaYeGJoWNnDtLoDVnc6I/view?usp=sharing

When I clicked on it or move it i get this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ykQoYfos4YR7GlHI753gQgMyrIMZPt69/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I get "access denied" for those links

Comment: Ah, I see. You use `stamper.GetOverContent(1)`. This already prepares the page content stream for the addition of new content, and already this preparation is considered a change of page content. Thus, don't use that method.

Comment: When I removed getoverContent it worked there is no corruption when i opened the file. But the image doesn't appear.

Comment: byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\\11.jpg");
 string base64Im= Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);

            var pdfStringValue ="<?xml version='1.0'?><body xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'" +
                   "xmlns:xfa='http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/' " +
                   "xfa:APIVersion='Acrobat:9.5.5' xfa:spec='2.0.2'>" +
                   $"<img src='data:image/jpg;base64,{base64Im}'" +
                   $" alt='G' width='500' height='600'></body>";
            stamp.Put(PdfName.RC, new PdfString(pdfStringValue));

Comment: Here is code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e6Xyk-_hJ6L4JNnTkGDLfinqBq15U3SS/view?usp=sharing

and output 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1maHJR_LglCd6grGtf2mzFh2g_o7cMQ5n/view?usp=sharing

Comment: No, don't try creating a **RC** containing that image. **RC** entries are used only in rich text fields. Instead keep to your original code and merely create `PdfAppearance` differently, without retrieving an `OverContent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
```

is the line causing the invalidation of the signature.

Calling `stamper.GetOverContent` (or `stamper.GetUnderContent`) already prepares the page contents for the addition of new content. This preparation already is considered a change of page content. As page content changes to a signed PDF are forbidden, this invalidates the signature.

You only use this `PdfContentByte cb` to create a `PdfAppearance` for your stamp annotation:

```
PdfAppearance app = cb.CreateAppearance(100, 100);
```

Fortunately you don't need `cb` to create a `PdfAppearance`, there also is a static `PdfAppearance` method to do so. Thus, simply replace

```
PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
PdfAppearance app = cb.CreateAppearance(100, 100);
```

by

```
PdfAppearance app = PdfAppearance.CreateAppearance(stamper.Writer, 100, 100);
```

Comment: Yes, it's working thank u.
 but still when I double click clicked on the ann or move it gives me at least one signature that needs validating. is that normal?
When I add stamp from adobe then save pdf then open it again and double click ann or moving it it doesnt give me the same issue

Comment: Well, the PDF standard allows a number of variations on how annotations are built. PDF viewers and processors certainly have to understand all those variations. When *changing* an annotations generated by another party, though, they usually prefer to change the internal annotation presentation into the structure they would create themselves. Maybe Adobe Reader after changing the annotation structure displays that "at least one signature that needs validating" message?

Comment: Anyways, it is not clear to me why Adobe Reader, after a change it did itself, finds out validating is necessary but does not re-validate automatically.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong way :

```
    var pdfContentByte = st.GetOverContent(1);
    Image sigimage = Image.GetInstance(bytes);
    pdfContentByte.AddImage(sigimage);
```

Calling `stamper.GetOverContent` (or `stamper.GetUnderContent`) caused the problem. I was adding signature images as an independent content to the PDF pdfContentByte, which is **altering the document content**, thus **invalidating existing signatures**.

The solution was to add the images with the stamp like this:

First, allow incremental updates (

```
    PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite), '\0', null, true);
```

Second, add the image with the signature appearance itself

```
        Image sigimage = Image.GetInstance(bytes);
        sap.Image = sigimage; // sap is the signature appearance
```

Last, set the renderer to Description( so you can get both the text and the image you added to the signature appearance

```
        sap.Render = PdfSignatureAppearance.SignatureRender.Description;
```

Hope this helps